# Django form error messages keys

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to override default form for error messages and the way I am doing it is like below:

```
default_error_list = {
  'required': 'error message 1',
  'invalid': 'error message 2'
}
class JoinForm(forms.Form):
  username = forms.CharField(error_messages=default_error_list)
```

Can someone tell me where I can find all possible keys of errors: (required, invalid, etc.)

Comment: This is explicitly covered in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#built-in-field-classes): *In the built-in Field classes section below, each Field defines the error message keys it uses.*

Comment: Thanks. Got it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the official Django documentation for the built-in fields there is a section exactly for what you are asking [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield)

For your above example is:

**CharField**

- required
- max_length
- min_length

Comment: Thank you. Perfectly, that is what I need.

Comment: No problem. If that solved your question consider to accept the answer